# How do I ensure full coverage of a localization resource file in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, localization, localizable.strings

lets say I have created a Windows Form application, written in C# (or VB), using Visual Studio (2012).

My application is targeted at an English speaking audience as well as at an German speaking.

Therefore, I've created two resource files (.resx) which contain the strings I am i.e. using in various `MessageBox`es. Something like: `MessageBox.Show(rm.GetString("file_not_found"), MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);`

How do I make sure that the string resource `"file_not_found"` is contained in my .resx files? How do I ensure a full coverage?

Visual Studio does not offer a check at compile time that makes sure that my resource strings are all contained in the resource files!

I do not want my application to crash when it is unable to find a resource string at runtime...

Edit:
I am accessing my resources using:
`internal static ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("myNamespace.Resources.lang", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());`

And I have manually created two (non auto generated) resources files, `lang.de_DE.resx` and `lang.en_GB.resx`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't come across that way of accessing resource strings before. I'm always able to access resources in a strongly-typed way. E.g. assuming I've got a resources file called Resource1.resx, and I've added a string resource named "file_not_found" then I can access it like so:-

```
MessageBox.Show(Resource1.file_not_found)
```

Comment: +1. Auto-generated CS file for RESX is the easiest way to achieve compile time verification. You may need to adjust tool used for particular resx file in your solution if for some reason corresponding Resource1.designer.cs file is not auto-generated.

Comment: Hi Andrew, so there is no need for something like this: internal static ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("myNamespace.Resources.lang", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()); ??

Comment: @Sebastian I've only ever used the above static/strongly-typed approach. Perhaps there is someone better qualified to explain the scenarios where ResourceManager would be used?

Comment: Thanks @AndrewStephens, your hint was the missing puzzle to solve my problem!